# Send ASP.NET web controller a list of objects in the query params

Tags: asp.net, flutter, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it clear why `discriminatorTags` query param is coming into my asp.net web controller as an empty list when I'm trying to send it as a list with one item?

```
[HttpGet("searchall")]
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<VgnItmEstSearchDto>> SearchAll(
    [FromQuery(Name = "searchterm")] string searchTerm = "",
    [FromQuery(Name = "currentpage")] int pageNumber = 1,
    [FromQuery(Name = "pagesize")] int pageSize = 6,
    [FromQuery(Name = "hasEst")] bool hasEst = true,
    [FromQuery(Name = "discriminatorTags")] List<DiscriminatorTags> discriminatorTags = null
    )
{
    var results = service.SearchAll(searchTerm, pageNumber, pageSize, hasEst, discriminatorTags);
    return Ok(results);
}
```

It's sending this url request (sorry it won't let me copy paste it) so I guess the issue is in here (how should `discriminatorTags` url encoding here be formatted differently?):

[image]

This is the C# stuct I want to send a list of:

```
public struct DiscriminatorTags : IDiscriminatorTags
{
    public DiscriminatorTags(List<int> tags, string discriminator, bool selected)
    {
        this.Tags = tags;
        this.Discriminator = discriminator;
        this.Selected = selected;
    }

    [Required]
    public List<int> Tags { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Discriminator { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

I ran swagger (I couldn't get any swagger api requests to work, it said there is either a CORS issue or network failure) and the generated url for this web request is:

http://localhost:5002/AllVgnItmEsts/searchall?currentpage=1&pagesize=6&hasEst=true&discriminatorTags=%7B%0A%20%20%22tags%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%201%0A%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%22discriminator%22%3A%20%22RestaurantItm%22%2C%0A%20%20%22selected%22%3A%20true%0A%7D

And when I paste the "discriminatorTags" portion of that into my api request url, `discriminatorTags` is still coming into my web controller as an empty list.

Comment: Why you not use Post method ? There is length limitiation in Get method. And I know this issue not related to this, if you want help, pls share you front-end code, so that we can easy to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET, it is not directly possible to bind a list of objects from a query parameter out of the box. However, you can achieve similar functionality by using a custom model binder or by manually parsing and binding the data.